# Python string format error

Tags: python

This is pretty basic:

```
my_name="nishant"
my_age=24
print "My name is %s"%my_name
print "My age is %d & my name is %s, what are you ?" %(my_age, my_name)
```

It works fine and prints the intended result, but if I replace the last line as this:

```
print "My age is %d & my name is %s, what are you ?" %my_age , %my_name
```

I get this error:

```
File "my_tests.py", line 7
  print "My age is %d & my name is %s, what are you ?" %my_age, %my_name
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My question is :

1. Why is `%(my_age, my_name)` != `%my_age , %my_name`?
2. How does Python interpret something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's performed by your snippet is [binary arithmetic operation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), and it require single object as second argument.

With parenthesis, you defining this argument as a two-element tuple. I added additional parenthesis to emphasise how code is interpreted.

```
print ("My age is %d & my name is %s, what are you ?" % (my_age, my_name))
```

When not, argument is single element and `, %my_name` is interpreted as second argument to  [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).

> print evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting
>   object to standard output

```
print ("My age is %d & my name is %s, what are you ?" % my_age), (%my_name)
```

Since `%my_name` is invalid Python expression, `SyntaxError` is raised.

Comment: this kinda makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

`%` is an operator just like `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `&`, `|`, etc.  Just as you can't do `4 * 5, * 6`, you can't do `'%s %s' % 'here', % 'there'`.  Actually, `x % y` is just a shortcut for `x.__mod__(y)`<sup>1</sup>.  Therefore,

```
'%s %s' % ('here', 'there') -> '%s %s'.__mod__(('here', 'there'))
```

Using `%` twice just doesn't make sense:

```
'%s %s'.__mod__('here'), .__mod__('there')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> or `y.__rmod__(x)` if `x.__mod__()` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print "My name is %s & my age is %d, what are you?" % (my_name, my_age)
My name is nishant & my age is 24, what are you?
```

After the % sign you pass in a tuple of the variables you need.

Sorry, I misinterpreted your question in my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

because formatter expects a tuple.

Comment: you meant if you want multiple formats in your string to print multiple variables, you need to put them inside ( ) (parentheses) separated by , (commas). ?

Comment: yes a % and tuple containing number of variables equal to % in string

Answer (score 0):

It's the python syntax for strings, you can read the python documentation for how a conversion specifier with more than two variables work:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

It's just a design solution, that the developers thought was best. Python expects a tuple, when there is more than one variable.

Comment: @NishantSingh You have two values, need to wrap them as a ```tuple```.

Comment: Because, that's how the developers of Python wanted it to be. It's a design solution for putting variables inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator should only appear once - it is not part of the variable name. This is how you would usually see it used:

```
print "My age is %d & my name is %s, what are you ?" % (my_age, my_name)
```

The space between the `%` and the tuple is just to emphasise their distinctness.